# New type of Variable for Tkinter textvariables?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use `textvariable`s in `Entry` and `Label` widgets. The problem is that I want my variables to always be `float`s rounded to two decimal digits. I thought an effective way to do this is to create a new type of Tkinter `Variable` that will output as a formatted `str`, while keeping the true `float` value as an internal value.

I looked at the code in tkinter's `__init__.py` to help set up my variable class:

```
class FormatDoubleVar(tk.Variable):
    _default = 0.0
    def __init__(self, iDecimal = 2):
        tk.Variable.__init__(self)
        self.decimal = iDecimal
        self.fValue = 0

    # convert strings back to float to save f value.
    def set(self, iValue):
        if isinstance(iValue, str):
            iValue = float(iValue.replace(",",""))
        self.fValue = round(float(iValue),self.decimal)
        fmtstr = "{:,." + str(self.decimal) + "f}"
        value = fmtstr.format(self.fValue)
        return self._tk.globalsetvar(self._name, value)

    def getValue(self):
        return self.fValue
```

However, when I use this variable for my `Entry` widget, I can't see to access the value I enter into the `Entry` through variable itself. I attached a callback to the `Entry` and the values of the `textvariable` assigned remain my old value no matter what I change it to when I run the program.

Is this an issue because I didn't create the class correctly? I notice in the tkinter source code that the other variables only overload the `get()` method, but I need the values to be formatted during `set()`, too.

Comment: your indentation is incorrect

Comment: fixed indentation

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter variables are not Python objects at all; they exist entirely within the Tcl interpreter that Tk is hosted within.  The Python side is just a reference to the automatically-generated name of the Tcl variable.  As such, any overridden methods only affect Python method calls, not the underlying variable.  Anything done entirely on the Tcl side (such as typing into an Entry widget with an associated textvariable) does not see your overrides.

Comment: Thanks. I realized the issue was that editing the Entry widget was updating the underlying variable - 'self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name)' - but wasn't updating the "fValue" variable I was using. What I had to do was update the "getValue" method to pull the variable from self._tk to access the changes. Thanks!